# Как отсортировать список и найти количество различных значений?

Tags: python, list

Мне нужно отсортировать список и найти количество различных значений.

К примеру я ввожу в переменную `n` значение `5` и мне выводит список `[0, 1, 2, 0, 2]` и потом выводит что там 3 дубликата, когда их здесь только два, я не понимаю этого.

```
import random

count = 0
n = int(input())
b = []
a = [b.append(random.randint(0, 5)) for i in range(n)]
print(b)
for i in range(len(b) - 1):
    if b.count(b[i]) > 1:
        count += 1
print(f"Количество дупликатов в списке B: {count}")
print("Количество уникальных значений")
```

Количество дупликатов я так просто вывожу, но и тут тоже неправильно...

Comment: Не дупликаты, а число различных значений. В списке 01202 три разных значения 012.

Comment: А вы бы не могли объяснить чуть поподробнее почему так получается? :)

Comment: вы не проверяете последнее значение. Замените `range(len(b) - 1)` на `range(len(b))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы усложняете себе жизнь, возможно короче применением класса `Counter`:

```
import random
from collections import Counter

n = int(input())
b = [random.randint(0, 5) for i in range(n)]
print(b)

occurrences = Counter(b)
print(f"Количество уникальных значений: {len(occurrences)}")
```

---

*Тест:*

- Ввод:
  `5`
- Вывод:
  `[2, 1, 4, 1, 3]`
  `Количество уникальных значений: 4`

---

*Объяснение:*

В библиотеке Питона находится модуль `collections` и в нем класс `Counter`  («счет»), который **все подсчитает за вас**.

Пример применения:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> Counter([5, 6, 7, 6, 7])
```

> ```
> Counter({6: 2, 7: 2, 5: 1})
> ```

С объектом типа `Counter` вы можете работать как с любым словарем, причем

- ключи — отдельные уникальные элементы оригинального списка,
- значения ключей — количество нахождений ключа в оригинальном списке.

*Количество ключей точно то, что вы хотели,* достаточно только применить функцию `len()`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, вы и вправду облегчили мне жизнь)

Answer (score 2):

Сортировка списка:

```py
b.sort()
```

Количество различных значений:

```py
len(set(b))
```